# How to add js file to Page Templates wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I created a Page Templates for Hello elementor template using Bootstrap Framework ...
But whatever I do, I can not introduce the .js file as a template ...
Thank you for your help

```html
<?php
        /**
        * Template name: test
         */
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/account-page/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/account-page/css/woocommerce-style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/account-page/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/account-page/js/popper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/account-page/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/account-page/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any additional JavaScript files required by a theme should be loaded using wp_enqueue_script. This ensures proper loading and caching, and allows the use conditional tags to target specific pages. These are optional.

Enqueue your script like this:

`wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);`

$handle is the name for the script.

$src defines where the script is located.

$deps is an array that can handle any script that your new script depends on, such as jQuery.

$ver lets you list a version number.

$in_footer is a boolean parameter (true/false) that allows you to place your scripts in the footer of your HTML document rather then in the header, so that it does not delay the loading of the DOM tree.

Your enqueue function should look like this:

```
function my_theme_name_scripts() {
if ( is_page_template( 'test.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/account-page/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/account-page/js/popper.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/account-page/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_name_scripts' );
```

The function should be placed in functions.php in your child theme.

Please note conditional logic to make sure the function is being executed in your test.php page template only.

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your guide
I put the code in part functions.php of the template, but file .js still does not run in the template

Comment: Do you have the .js files in folder child theme/account-page/js/ ?